# Include D3 chart in html element like div or td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I recently started working with D3 charts in HTML, and most charts I've used seem to be added within an HTML element such as a `<div>`, `<td>`, etc.

In the case of this [D3 Radial bar Chart](https://bl.ocks.org/AntonOrlov/6b42d8676943cc933f48a43a7c7e5b6c), it seems that it's not part of an html element. For example, I wanted to add a border around it so I thought maybe to include in inside a div or a table and then add the border to the html element. But I have no idea how to include it within these elements. Essentially, the HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
   // This is where the control is drawn
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, let's say I wanted to include it inside a `DIV` so that I could add a border around it, then how can I do that?

In my case, the issue is that the chart uses up the whole horizontal space. It's as if the chart is inside a div that stretches 100% horizontally.

Here's the code. Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Household monthly electricity consumption</title>
<style>
body {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

svg {
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: block;
}

path.arc {
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

path.arc:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.axis line, .axis circle  {
  stroke: #cccccc;
  stroke-width: 1px
}

.axis circle {
  fill: none;
}

.r.axis text {
  text-anchor: end
}

</style>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
const width = 960,
  height = 500,
  chartRadius = height / 2 - 40;

const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

let svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

let tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
  .attr('class', 'tooltip');

const PI = Math.PI,
  arcMinRadius = 10,
  arcPadding = 10,
  labelPadding = -5,
  numTicks = 10;


d3.csv('energy.csv', (error, data) => {

  let scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value) * 1.1])
    .range([0, 2 * PI]);

  let ticks = scale.ticks(numTicks).slice(0, -1);
  let keys = data.map((d, i) => d.name);
  //number of arcs
  const numArcs = keys.length;
  const arcWidth = (chartRadius - arcMinRadius - numArcs * arcPadding) / numArcs;

  let arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius((d, i) => getInnerRadius(i))
    .outerRadius((d, i) => getOuterRadius(i))
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle((d, i) => scale(d))

  let radialAxis = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'r axis')
    .selectAll('g')
      .data(data)
      .enter().append('g');

  radialAxis.append('circle')
    .attr('r', (d, i) => getOuterRadius(i) + arcPadding);

  radialAxis.append('text')
    .attr('x', labelPadding)
    .attr('y', (d, i) => -getOuterRadius(i) + arcPadding)
    .text(d => d.name);

  let axialAxis = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'a axis')
    .selectAll('g')
      .data(ticks)
      .enter().append('g')
        .attr('transform', d => 'rotate(' + (rad2deg(scale(d)) - 90) + ')');

  axialAxis.append('line')
    .attr('x2', chartRadius);

  axialAxis.append('text')
    .attr('x', chartRadius + 10)
    .style('text-anchor', d => (scale(d) >= PI && scale(d) < 2 * PI ? 'end' : null))
    .attr('transform', d => 'rotate(' + (90 - rad2deg(scale(d))) + ',' + (chartRadius + 10) + ',0)')
    .text(d => d);

  //data arcs
  let arcs = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'data')
    .selectAll('path')
      .data(data)
      .enter().append('path')
      .attr('class', 'arc')
      .style('fill', (d, i) => color(i))

  arcs.transition()
    .delay((d, i) => i * 200)
    .duration(1000)
    .attrTween('d', arcTween);

  arcs.on('mousemove', showTooltip)
  arcs.on('mouseout', hideTooltip)


  function arcTween(d, i) {
    let interpolate = d3.interpolate(0, d.value);
    return t => arc(interpolate(t), i);
  }

  function showTooltip(d) {
    tooltip.style('left', (d3.event.pageX + 10) + 'px')
      .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 25) + 'px')
      .style('display', 'inline-block')
      .html(d.value);
  }

  function hideTooltip() {
    tooltip.style('display', 'none');
  }

  function rad2deg(angle) {
    return angle * 180 / PI;
  }

  function getInnerRadius(index) {
    return arcMinRadius + (numArcs - (index + 1)) * (arcWidth + arcPadding);
  }

  function getOuterRadius(index) {
    return getInnerRadius(index) + arcWidth;
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

The script in your example create a new `svg` element and attach it to the `body`:

```
d3.select('body').append('svg')
```

If you want - you can add a border around that svg:

```
svg {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Or another option - you can append that `svg` element to some other element in your page (some other `div`) and style that `div` element.

```
d3.select('div#div-id').append('svg')
```

Comment: Can I move the `<script></script>` in `body` to somewhere outside `body`? Then in `body` I would have one line to display the d3 chart.

Comment: I doesn't really matter, you can have that script in the `body` or in the `head`